# Swift JSON parsing returns empty array

Tags: swift

I am trying to parse a JSON object from an API, I have defined the structure of JSON in a separate file.

The parser successfully parses the JSON file, however when calling the `getStandings()` function in `viewDidLoad()` it returns an empty array.
Can anyone tell me where's my error?

This is the structure of the JSON

EDIT: I went through the similar question however none of the solutions are working on my code, can someone please explain what needs to be added to my code, I am new to this

```
struct FootballData : Codable{
    let response: [Response]
}

struct Response: Codable {
    let league: League
}

struct League: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let country: String
    let standings : [[Standings]]
}

struct Standings: Codable {
    let rank: Int
    let team: Team
    let points: Int
    let goalsDiff: Int
    let all: All
}

struct Team: Codable {
    let id: Int
    let name: String
    let logo: String
}

struct All: Codable {
    let played: Int
    let win: Int
    let draw: Int
    let lose: Int
}
```

Here's the code I am using to request data from the API and parse the JSON file.

```
    func getStandings() -> [[Standings]]{
        let standings = [[Standings]]()
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://v3.football.api-sports.io/standings?league=39&season=2022")!,timeoutInterval: Double.infinity)
        request.addValue("639248abcf96cbcebd90cd66aec49db4", forHTTPHeaderField: "x-rapidapi-key")
        request.addValue("v3.football.api-sports.io", forHTTPHeaderField: "x-rapidapi-host")
        request.httpMethod = "GET"
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
            if error == nil && data != nil {
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                do {
                    let decodedData = try decoder.decode(FootballData.self, from: data!)
                    let standings = decodedData.response[0].league.standings
                    print(standings)
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
        }
        //4. Start the task
        task.resume()
        return standings
    }
```

Comment: You are missing the asynchrone concept. replace `print(standings)` with `print("Inside closure: \(standings))"`, and between `task.resume()` and `return standings` add `print("returning value: \(standings)")`. What's the output in console? the print order? Which order did you expect? To handle it, search for either "Swift + Async + Closure", or "Swift await" (new in recent Swift).

Comment: @Larme Thanks for your answer, I read through what you mentioned however I am still stuck, can you please point out what exactly needs to be added to my code, as I am new to this concept.

Comment: @ZCoder Look at [Rob's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25203556/returning-data-from-async-call-in-swift-function/54597264#54597264) `async` answer in the duplicate.